# Reference Request: Vedanta Sutras

Tags: vedanta, brahma-sutras, reference-request

I already have copies of the commentaries by Adi Shankaracharya and Shri Ramanuja. Since I want to understand the Vedanta Sutras from different angles, I also want an English copy of the Govinda Bhasya of the Vedanta Sutras. I tried looking online, but the ones I found contained off-topic comments (one brought in Quantum Physics and I doubt that the Govinda Bhasya would talk about that). If possible, please provide a copy or tell me where I can find one (URL Link, etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know there are several English translations available online, but none of them is of great translation quality, namely they either have additional comments by the translator himself which they did not separate from Baladeva's text but they, unfortunately, incorporated into the Baladeva's text, and thus you don't know what exactly Baladeva wrote. Or their translation is not literal, and it's not complete.

There is, however, one translation, it's by Bhanu Swami, but I haven't read that one and I can't estimate whether it's good. That one is not available online for free reading, I think. If you are interested to buy it just google for it.

Comment: Thank you for the reference. I will take a look.